# Generic class for jupyter widgets

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I'm attempting to create a class to easily create and generate jupyter widgets for dashboards in my notebooks. This class so far has an add_row and display method. I'm having trouble finding a way to easily pass parameters to the widget object as different widgets require different things (instead of using a 100 if statements for each widget). It works fine for TextBox at the moment but I want to extend it to get it to work with all widgets.

Here's a sample of the add_row method:

```
# types: Type of widgets ex: ['Text', 'Text', 'Text']
# labels: Label names ['A', 'B', 'C']
# values: Default values ['', '', '']

for i in range(len(labels)):
    w = getattr(widgets, types[i])

    row.append(w(description=labels[i], value=values[i]))

self.rows.append(widgets.HBox(row))
```

Answer (score 0):

I've worked up a simple class for this, you need to pass a list of dictionaries to the `add_rows` method, where each dict has the  widget `class` you want to create, plus any extra `kwargs` which you need to create the widget. It should work for any widget type as long as you provide the correct kwargs.

```python
import ipywidgets as ipyw

class WidgetAppender:

    def __init__(self):
        self.box = ipyw.VBox()
        display(self.box)

    def add_rows(self, list_of_dicts):
        for input_dict in list_of_dicts:
            widget_class = input_dict.pop('class')
            widget = widget_class(**input_dict)
            self.box.children = self.box.children + (widget,)

wa = WidgetAppender()
display(wa)

wa.add_rows(
[{'class': ipyw.Text, 'description':'Hi'},
 {'class': ipyw.Checkbox, 'value': False}]
)
```